# Magento 2 how to add Register , Wishlist , Login block to header.panel?

Tags: magento2, register

I'm using magento 2 and I'm trying to add the Register , Wishlist, Login links to my tob bar, into header.panel , what's the properly code to add that from xml, or any other way ?

Comment: This is comes inside panel header class at which place you want to display it

Comment: I've just did it by adding this in my defaul.xml file <move element="register-link" destination="header.panel" after="minicart.topnav"/>   now I'm just trying to find the element for wishlist , how do I find the right element names ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use follow code in your file default.xml:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="wishlist-link" before="-" ifconfig="guestwishlist/general/addlink">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wishlist</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">wishlist</argument>

            </arguments>
        </block>

    </referenceBlock>


</body>
```